# SQL Order By Except When You Don't

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I want to retrieve a full table with some of the values sorted. The sorted values should all appear before the unsorted values. I though I could pull this off with a UNION but order by is only valid to use after unioning the table and my set of data isn't set up such that that is useful in this case. I want rows with a column value of 0-6 to show up sorted in DESC order and then the rest of the results to show up after that. Is there some way to specify a condition in the order by clause? I saw something that looked close to what I wanted to so but I couldn't get the equality condition working in sql. I'm going to try to make a query using WHEN cases but I'm not sure if there's a way to specify a case like currentValue <= 6. If anyone has any suggestions that would be awesome.

Comment: To answer this you will need to specify what specific database/SQL implementation you are using as this is not possible in 'generic' SQL but can likely be achieved using the proprietary extensions in your environment (TSQL, PL/SQL, etc.)

Comment: see here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956120/oracle-dynamic-desc-and-asc-in-order-by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
order by (case when currentValue <= 6 then 1 else 0 end) desc,
         (case when currentValue <= 6 then column end) desc
```

The first puts the values you care about first.  The second puts them in sorted order.  The rest will be ordered arbitrarily.

Comment: +1 but shouldn't the 1 and 0 be reversed if the OP wants values 1-6 to be sorted before the rest of the values?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourdata
ORDER BY CASE WHEN yourColumn BETWEEN 0 AND 6 THEN yourColumn ELSE -1 End Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

One RDBMS-agnostic solution would be to add a second field that takes the same value as the field you wish to sort when that field is less than or equal to six. Then just sort by that field.